# Java Load sequence file from hdfs as JavaRDD<Vector>

Tags: java, vector, apache-spark, hdfs

I have the following method to write file to `HDFS`

```
public void writePointsToFile(Path path, FileSystem fs, Configuration conf,
        List<Vector> points) throws IOException {

    SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf,
            Writer.file(path), Writer.keyClass(LongWritable.class),
            Writer.valueClass(Vector.class));

    long recNum = 0;

    for (Vector point : points) {
        writer.append(new LongWritable(recNum++), point);
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

I need to know how to read this file as `JavaRDD<Vector>` to be used in `Spark Clustering K-mean`?

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern with Spark is to transform immutable objects into new ones so transforming a DRM (Mahout distributed row matrix) or collections of Mahout Vectors is the way you should do this. So not sure what you are asking.

Comment: can you please tell me how to transfer `VectorWritable (org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable)`  which is coming from a sequence file generated by Mahout and I would like to convert that into Vector (org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors) type is Spark. How can I do that in java?